# Set Minimum Height of a Frame?

Tags: html, css

My frames are as follows:

```
<Frameset rows="45%,*">
<Frame name = "navigation" src = "navigation.html" " marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<Frame name = "Index" src="HTML Structure.html">
</Frameset>
```

I've allowed for the `navigation` frame to be resized, but I want to set a minimum and maximum value for the frame height. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using framesets? This method of making a webpage hasn't been widely used since around about 1999.

Comment: Frameset specification on w3schools shows you all standard attributes etc. You'd need to just use inline styles on the frameset/frames to do what you want to do: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp

Comment: Agh, I just figured the easiest way to create a navbar that's independent of the main page is to use frames. Is there a more efficient way (using div, for example)? Sorry if I'm being ignorant; I'm brand new to web programming.

Comment: If you're new to front end development then the best thing to do is start at the beginning and read some books/online tutorials on how to do the basics. You'll simply want a nav div at the top of your page and a content div under it. That's obviuously being very simplistic. Good luck.

Comment: Ahh yeah I'll work on that as well. I've been reading through some tutorials for HTML help, but I might have picked up an outdated book because it does a lot of frame stuff... Where in the inline styles for frames do you see a setting for min/max heights?

Comment: Honestly, forget about the frames :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
<div id="wrap">

 <div id="nav"></div>

 <div id="content"></div>

</div>
```

With some css like this:

```
body {
 text-align:center;
}    


div#wrap {
 width:960px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

div#nav {
 width:960px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}

div#content {
 width:960px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

The above should get you started but the possibilities are obviously virtually limitless.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll follow up if I have any more questions.

Comment: Is there a built-in way to call the "nav" mark-up code on multiple pages? For example, I want it included on every page, and it's always going to go under the tag "div id = "nav" ". Do I have to physically copy it into every page, or is there a cleaner way?

In other words, can I save the `<div id = "nav">` as an HTML file, and then somehow include it in every page on my website?

Comment: @deathmastar0 - Depends how your pages are being built. The simplest way is to use PHP. SO basically you cut out your nav section, your footer section and whatever else is repeated on every page and put them into separate files. Then on your main pages you simply call those files onto the page. A quick bit of Google action should show you how to do this.

Comment: @deathmastar0 If this answer is helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer to others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know about the accepted answer thing. I'll make sure to do that in the future. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  The OP asks about frames yet this answer focuses on DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

max-height property, similar to the way you would implement a div width and height in CSS.

Comment: Hmm I think I'm still doing it wrong. Here's what I have:

<style>
div.dimensions {max-height: 400px; min-height: 50px;}
</style>

<Frameset rows="45%,*">
 <div class = "dimensions">
 <Frame name = "navigation" src = "navigation.html" " marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" >
 </div>
 <Frame name = "Index" src="HTML Structure.html">
</Frameset>

Is this not what you meant?